# Help getting corresponding dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, data, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
self.thisSession_df:
    id   exerciseId  sets
    1       1         12  
    2       1         14
    2       2         15
    2       2         15

self.exercises_df:
    id   exerciseName
    1      Squat        
    2      Pullup
```

I would like to find a way to replace the `exerciseId` in `self.thisSession_df` with the corresponding name from `self.exercises_df`

Hopeful result:

```
self.thisSession_df:
    id   exerciseId    sets
    1       Squat       12  
    2       Squat       14
    2       Pullup      15
    2       Pullup      15
```

I tried a solution that I found on here and modified it to come up with:
`self.thisSession_df['exerciseId'] = self.thisSession_df['exerciseId'].map(df1.set_index('id')['exerciseName'])`

This gives me error: `string indices must be integers`

I would appreciate a nudge in right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend merging your two dataframes to get the exercise names:

```py
exercise_name_df = thisSession_df.merge(exercises_df, left_on='exerciseId', right_on='id')
```

This will give you a dataframe like

```
exercise_name_df:
    id   exerciseId  sets  exerciseName
    1       1         12      Squat
    2       1         14      Squat
    2       2         15     Pullup
    2       2         15     Pullup
```

Then you can replace `exerciseId` with the name if you really want to:

```py
# reassign id to name
exercise_name_df['exerciseId'] = exercise_name_df['exerciseName']
# drop redundant column
exercise_name_df.drop(columns=['exerciseName'], inplace=True)
```

I would argue that the above method is more readable than the `map()` solution. But I think the `map()` solution should also work with a small tweak:

```py
thisSession_df['exerciseId'] = thisSession_df['exerciseId'].map(exercises_df.set_index('id')['exerciseName'])
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!